# Nativescript - swipe gestures not working reliably

Tags: nativescript

I've got a listview and would like to get notification of swipe-down events.

In the loaded event, I have:

`

```
   let listview = page.getViewById("listView");

    listview.on(gestures.GestureTypes.swipe, (args: gestures.SwipeGestureEventData) =>
    {
        console.log("Swipe dir=" + args.direction );

    });
```

`

I do get swipe notifications - but I have to swipe more than a few times.

Swipe up seems to work better than swipe down.

This behavior is the same on emulator and Android device.

I changed it to

`<ListView id="listView" swipe="onItemSwipe">..</ListView>`

Same behavior...initially difficult to get both swipe UP and DOWN to work. After some time UP starts to work and then DOWN...but intermittent initially and then more reliably...but not 100%

Comment: is your listview wrapped in a ScrollView or another component that has gestures in it that could be intercepting the gestures?

Comment: Hey @dashman based on your code I have created this test application and on both iOS and Android the swipe is triggered problem free https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/stackoverflow/listviewSwipe

Comment: I tried this and am not even getting the callback. I am using TNS 2.5.